# Is this kind of answer acceptable?

Tags: discussion

In this recent question [Why is the double bass the only instrument in the violin family tuned in fourths?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33522/why-is-the-double-bass-the-only-instrument-in-the-violin-family-tuned-in-fourths), there was [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/33528/7356):

> The early history (from about 1500 to 1850) of bass tunings are very variable, with anything from 3 to 6 strings and tunings in anything from thirds to fifths. Reference.
>
> In the classical period, the virtuoso Domenico Dragonetti played a 3-string bass tuned C G D an octave below the cello, which was more or less the standard instrument that Haydn, Mozart and Beethoven wrote for.
>
> The current "standard" (E A D G tuning with a string extension down to low C) is a relatively modern invention.

This answer has 6 upvotes and 1 downvote, but it *doesn't address the question*. The question is clearly about **Why** the bass is tuned in fourths. But this answer says this kind of tuning is relatively new, and earlier in history there were other tunings as well.

I flagged this post, but it was declined

> declined - I don't think the questions presupposition of an explicit reason makes this answer less useful.

I do think that it is useful as a comment, but as an answer to the question per  se, isn't it a bit useless?

Comment: The answer reads to me as "A bunch of different things have been used, we happened to settle on this." There's not a clear single originator with a clear single purpose.

Comment: I think it was a good answer.  I, personally, like a bit of context to the answers, so the user might've been adding to the previous answers, as an edit with this added info would've been rejected.

Comment: Downvote it. This is what downvotes are for. the tooltip reads: "This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear or not useful**". emphasis mine. that answer definitely falls in the unclear and not useful place.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say *useless*, but I would say that the poster needs to draw a clear correlation between the information and addressing the question.  The way it is currently written, it's implying that basses are tuned in 4ths because it is the most recent / current tuning style / preference for instrumentalists.

While I am unconvinced as to the validity of this correlation, such a correlation would need to be more clearly made before it could be refuted.